# Facebook Mobile App Install Ads Error - Page you requested was not found

Tags: ios, facebook, ads

I'm trying to use the new facebook mobile app installs. I integrated the newest SDK in my app and followed this [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/mobile-app-ads/).

In the documentation it says:
"Note: to confirm the SDK is setup for measurement, go to the app summary page and there's a field "Last Mobile Install Reported" that provides times stamp on the last time your app reported an install."

I can confirm that installs are being reported and that works properly.

When I try to make an ad, and click the Preview link - instead of it going to the App Store it goes to a facebook error page that says: "The page you requested was not found. You may have clicked an expired link or mistyped the address. Some web addresses are case sensitive."

I can see that the actual URL is `www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=MYAPPID`

All the ads get automatically denied because they direct to the error page instead of the app store.

On my app Page, I have filled out the required info and only have it setup as Native iOS app (facebook login enabled, deep linking enabled). My app store id is in there, and if I click the "Go to Itunes Store" link, its working properly.

Under the 'Advanced' setting, I made sure to choose Native/Desktop app. Any suggestions?

Comment: are you problem on both simulator and device

Answer (score 1):

Setting up a Page for your App might help resolve the issue. The Ad tool preview link is attempting to redirect to your App Page, which probably doesn't exist yet, so it's throwing an error.

The page must have the same name as your page, and you'll be able to link them together from your App Settings page.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the root folder of your project
2. Type: grep -r advertisingIdentifier .

This will recursively check every file, and give you the name of the offending library

Try new Facebook SDK and add frameworks social.framework, adsupport.framework and accounts.framework and make the status of the as option